# get a current object by id from firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: fire base object]

how get the current object by id from firebase in Android
thanks

-users
      KiCjMVv7J3oCjLEg1Lt <<<<<<<<<<<------ID from object
 -adress:presa
 -number:6

Comment: What do you want to do? get the data from that user?

Comment: It is hard to understand what problem you have from your current question. It sounds like you're stuck with a specific piece of code. You'll find that you get most help if you post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful).